# Will setting HstsOptions.IncludeSubDomains from an app hosted in a sub domain, affect other sub domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dns, subdomain, hsts

I've got an ASP.NET Core 3 application, which is hosted under a sub-domain.

If I set `HstsOptions.IncludeSubDomains` to `true`, will that make changes to other domains/apps hosted to the main domain, or it will be sub-domains on even lower level (for example if I'm `yo.hello.example`, affected sub-domains will be `yo.bo.hello.example?` Domains like `boom.hello.example` won't be affected?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If set up correctly and as you describe it should only affect lower sub-domains and not sibling sub-domains nor parent domains.